# Drawing with XOR in Quartz

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Let's say I'm porting some application to Mac OS X and in some cases it renders text and caret using Xor operation under other platform. Research has shown that XOR operation is not supported by Quartz drawing functions. Am I correct? And what alternative can be used to port such pieces of code to Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that XOR is a bitmap operation (and binary, really, hence only defined for b/w) so it is only defined when drawing one bitmap over another. Quartz provides a wide variety of bitmap blend modes, including Difference (`kCGBlendModeDifference`) and Exclusion (`kCGBlendModeExclusion`) which are both exactly XOR for b/w values - so, yes, Quartz does support XOR.

The way you can do this in practice is to get an image of your caret (white caret on black background) and draw it using either of the above blend modes (see `CGContextSetBlendMode`). If you meant to draw the text using XOR as well, then you draw it into an image context (again, white on black) and then apply the image context with the blend mode to your target.

Comment: There's also [`kCGBlendModeXOR`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGBlendModeXOR), but that's alpha-based rather than color-based. More importantly, the blend modes aren't restricted to drawing rasters—you can set the blend mode for any operations, including fills and strokes. You can draw the caret (for example) directly; you don't need to draw it into an image first.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not true that QuickDraw XOR mode is "only defined for b/w". For example, the original description in Inside Macintosh, Color Quickdraw, for the "srcXor" mode is:

where source pixel is black, invert the destination pixel--for a colored destination pixel, use the complement of its color if the pixel is direct, invert its index if the pixel is indexed.